# Вывод текста не по всей длине

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит не на всю страницу текст. Вот Html

```css
.low-block .thumbnail {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.low-block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="low-block">
  <div>
    <h4 class="header" align="center">Subcontract Fee:</h4>
    <span class="thumbnail">
         Should you have any questions or need additional in
         formation, please do not hesitate to contact us. 
         Please sign and return ASAP, listing the year, make
          and model of the vehicle you will provide.
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: все работает нормально, посмотрите предыдущий тег, или может какой стиль затерялся

Comment: Ты откуда этот атрибут откопал, `align="center"`? Им еще динозавры пользовались...  И почему текст должен быть на всю страницу?

Comment: @Air, а как тогда сделать по центру выравнивание?

Comment: для этого есть `css`, забудь про эти древние атрибуты

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял ты этого хотел?

```css
.thumbnail {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span class="thumbnail">Should you have any questions or need additional in formation, please do not hesitate to contact us. Please sign and return ASAP, listing the year, make and model of the vehicle you will provide.</span>
```